Time zone day light saving changes problem
In my country, we no longer observe Daylight Saving Time. We now use Standard Time year-round.
Therefor a lot  of devices has run into problem. I used different approaches to fix this but just one of them works correctly.
I am trying to convert a epoch time to local time. For example
val epocTime = 1715244851730 // 12:24:11.730 PM GMT+03:30

When I use SimpleDateFormat, I get wrong result.
java.text.SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT))
.format(Date(time)) // 13:24

Also when I use java.time.LocalDateTime, I get wrong result
java.time.LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
    java.time.Instant.ofEpochMilli(epocTime),
    java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault()
) // 13:24:11.730

But when I use ThreeTen library, I get correct result
org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
    org.threeten.bp.Instant.ofEpochMilli(epocTime),
    org.threeten.bp.ZoneId.systemDefault(),
) // 12:24:11.730

So the question is: Isn't java time a replacement for ThreeTen library?

java.time and ThreeTen Backport are basically the same. Where each of them gets their time zone data on an Android device and in an Android simulator I don’t know. It looks like you need to update tzdata somewhere, which should be possible.

Android 10 and above should have received timezone data update regularly.
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2024/03/better-faster-stronger-time-zone-updates-on-android.html

Similar to Update Android tzdata files and my answer to Android - how to fix java.time.zone.ZoneRulesException: Unknown time-zone
Warning: to my understanding the emulator only has the tzdata from when the OS version was released and is NOT updated.
So for old devices which no longer get tzdata updates you'll need to use a third-party library like joda-time-android which seems to update tzdata with some frequency but be aware that you will need update your app if you want to maintain consistency with the current tzdata set.
A similar situation exists for the ThreeTenABP / ThreeTen Backport where you'll need to update the library to the most recent version to get tzdata updates.

Answer by Chang is correct: When the rules change for time zone of interest to your users, the time zone rules database must be updated. No computer is clairvoyant; you must inform each computer of change to rules.
Be aware that time zone rules (tzdata) needs to be updated in all these places:

Certain libraries such as Joda-Time and ThreeTen-Backport.
JVM
Database engines such as Postgres
Host operating system (system updates for Android OS, iOS, macOS, MS Windows, Linux, BSD, AIX, etc.)

You said:

I am trying to convert a epoch time to local time.

To parse a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 UTC (1970-01-01T00:00Z), use java.time.Instant class.
Here is an example in Java syntax, as I do not yet know Kotlin.
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_715_244_851_730L ) ;


When I use SimpleDateFormat,

No, never use SimpleDateFormat. The terribly flawed date-time classes from the early days of Java were years ago supplanted by the modern java.time classes defined in JSR 310.
An implementation of java.time is available in Android 26+. For earlier Android, modern tooling makes available most of the java.time functionality via “API Desugaring”.

lso when I use java.time.LocalDateTime, I get wrong result

No, never use LocalDateTime to represent a moment, a particular point on the timeline. That class contains only a date and a time-of-day, but lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So a LocalDateTime object is inherently ambiguous.
To represent a moment, a particular point on the timeline, use any of these three java.time classes:

Instant
OffsetDateTime
ZonedDateTime

In your case, use ZonedDateTime.
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tehran" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;

See this code run at Ideone.com.
2024-05-09T08:54:11.730Z
2024-05-09T13:24:11.730+04:30[Asia/Tehran]

Verify that DST is not observed at that moment.
ZoneRules rules = z.getRules() ;
boolean isDst = rules.isDaylightSavings( instant ) ; 


But when I use ThreeTen library, I get correct result

Presumably, you downloaded a fresh copy of ThreeTen-Backport that came with its own updated copy of tzdata. So it produces correct time zone adjustments, where as your other code produces wrong results by using an outdated tzdata file.

So the question is: Isn't java time a replacement for ThreeTen library?

Not exactly.
The ThreeTen-Backport library is, as the name suggests, a back-port of the java.time functionality in Java 8+ back to the older Java 6 & Java 7.
The API (class & method names, etc.) are virtually identical to facilitate eventual migration of old apps to modern Java.
There is really no longer any need for ThreeTen-Backport, as Java 6 & 7 are really old and unsupported. Apps should be migrated to a LTS version of Java. LTS versions include Java 8, 11, 17, and 21. All of these modern versions of Java include java.time classes. I highly recommend 17 & 21, as 8 is ending its life, and most any app that can run on 11 should be able to run on 17/21.
Do not confuse ThreeTen-Backport for ThreeTen-Extra. The second is a vital library that extends java.time with additional functionality.
